# XSD - How to describe an unordered set of element types where the first element must appear first in the sequence?

Tags: xml, schema, xsd

This is an XML schema question.

I know that `xsd:all` element can't appear in a sequence (must be the top level element of its type).

That is, I cannot use the following:

```
<xsd:complexType name="Application">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element ref="Name"></xsd:element>
    <xsd:all>
      <xsd:element ref="ADD"></xsd:element>
      <xsd:element ref="DELETE"></xsd:element>
    </xsd:all>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

My question is how to declare the "ADD" and "DELETE" elements above in any order (unordered set) but still make sure that the element "Name" would be the first and always appear.  (Think of the situation where I have not only "ADD" and "DELETE" but about 10 or more unordered elements set: ADD, DELETE, EDIT etc...)

IMPORTANT NOTE: the ADD and DELETE may appear only ONCE, but their order is not matter:

```
<Application>
  <NAME>
  <DELETE>
  <ADD>
</Application>
```

but NOT:

```
<Application>
  <NAME>
  <DELETE>
  <ADD>
  <DELETE> <!--cannot appear twice-->
</Application>
```

Answer (score 19):

If I understand your request you are right on track, the only thing you're missing is maxOccurs="unbounded" on your choice.

I created the following schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://someNamespace" xmlns="http://someNamespace" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Root" type="Application">
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="Application">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="Name"></xs:element>
      <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element ref="ADD"></xs:element>
        <xs:element ref="DELETE"></xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="Name"/>
  <xs:element name="ADD"/>
  <xs:element name="DELETE"/>
</xs:schema>
```

And it worked well for

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://someNamespace">
  <ns0:Name />
  <ns0:ADD />
  <ns0:ADD />
  <ns0:DELETE />
  <ns0:ADD />
  <ns0:DELETE />
  <ns0:DELETE />
</ns0:Root>
```

but not for

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://someNamespace">
  <ns0:ADD />
  <ns0:ADD />
  <ns0:DELETE />
  <ns0:ADD />
  <ns0:DELETE />
  <ns0:DELETE />
</ns0:Root>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I fine tunned my question above.
I meant that the ADD and DELETE should not appear 0 or 1 times, but their order is not matter.
"all" can't be used this case, because the NAME mandatory element can't come with "all".
Do you have any other solution?
Thank

Comment: It works only with maxOccurs="unbounded" attribute for choice tag

Answer (score 6):

I think you're looking for the "all" element, it allows for unordered list. However there are restrictions on the elements you can put in there. See http://www.w3.org/2005/07/xml-schema-patterns.html#Collection

Comment: <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1"> also describes an unordered list.

Answer (score 6):

I'm sorry you've been toiling with this problem for 7 years now with no answer.

I'm going to help by revisiting your assumptions.

By treating "Name" as a piece of data that must come first, and requiring that it must be a child of Application, and then in general saying you don't care about the order of its siblings, you're making a confusing situation for yourself. Why is Name a sibling of ADD and DELETE if it follows different rules and serves a different purpose?  If you had to model this in any other data structure, you wouldn't include "Name" in a list of things alongside "ADD" and "DELETE". You would say two things: An Application has a Name, and it also has a list of commands such as ADD and DELETE.

Since Name is a special thing as compared to ADD and DELETE, then it should be modeled separately from those other tags.

So, you can either make Name an attribute of Application, and keep Add and Delete as child elements, or you can keep Name as a child element but then surround ADD and DELETE with a placeholder/grouping tag, such as Commands. The Commands tag would be the only sibling of Name.

Here's a schema supporting Name as an attribute, with an arbitrary number of commands in any order. "Name as Attribute.xsd":

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Application" type="Application_Type" />
    <xs:complexType name="Application_Type">
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="ADD"/>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="DELETE"/>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="THIRD"/>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="FOURTH"/>
            </xs:all>
            <xs:attribute name="Name"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="ADD"/>
    <xs:element name="DELETE"/>
    <xs:element name="THIRD"/>  
    <xs:element name="FOURTH"/> 
</xs:schema>
```

Example XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Name="text" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Name as Attribute.xsd">
    <THIRD>text</THIRD>
    <ADD>text</ADD>
    <FOURTH>text</FOURTH>
    <DELETE>text</DELETE>
</Application>
```

And here's one with the commands nested within a placeholder tag. "Commands Grouping.xsd":

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Application" type="Application_Type"/>
    <xs:complexType name="Application_Type">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="Name"/>
            <xs:element name="Commands" type="Commands_Type"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="Commands_Type">
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="ADD"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="DELETE"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="THIRD"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="FOURTH"/>
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="Name"/>
    <xs:element name="ADD"/>
    <xs:element name="DELETE"/>
    <xs:element name="THIRD"/>
    <xs:element name="FOURTH"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Example XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Commands Grouping.xsd">
    <Name>text</Name>
    <Commands>
        <THIRD>text</THIRD>
        <ADD>text</ADD>
        <FOURTH>text</FOURTH>
        <DELETE>text</DELETE>
    </Commands>
</Application>
```

One note about either of these is that messages with zero commands are still valid message. Perhaps that's okay, but if it's a problem, perhaps that validation belongs in the Application layer rather than the XSD.

Answer (score 4):

You can implement unordered lists using the sequence type `xs:choice`.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xs:element name="Application"/>
  <xs:complexType>
   <xs:element name="NAME">
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="ADD" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="DELETE" type="xs:string"/>
     </xs:choice>
    </xs:element>
   </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This way you restrict the user from using any tag they want inside the `<NAME/>` element but allow them to use `<ADD/>` and `<DELETE/>` as often as they like.

Comment: Is the `<xs:sequence>` in there actually necessary, in this case?

Comment: @LarsH: Yes, as xs:choice permits only choosing one of the listed elements. xs:sequence here creates an unbounded / repeatable choice of ADD or DELETE.  However it doesn't meet the OP's requirement of never allowing more than one instance of ADD and DELETE each at a time.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe this can be done without enumerating every combination of ADD, DELETE etc. Generally speaking unordered lists don't play well, either with DTDs or schemas.

Comment: <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1"> describes an unordered list

Comment: @lbalazscs - From the question "IMPORTANT NOTE: the ADD and DELETE may appear only ONCE, but their order is not matter:". maxOccurs="unbounded" won't deliver that.

Comment: Alhoci, yes, the OP wanted an unordered SET, but unordered LISTS are still possible. I added this comment, because I was misled by your answer (I had another problem where the elements could appear any times), only to discover later that unordered lists are absolutely possible.